# How to search for a specific number of consecutive values above 0 in r?

Tags: r, loops, search

I need to create a function to search for at least 5 values above 0.

```
df1 <- c( M, A, T, A, N, S, I, I, V, L)
df2 <- c( 1.2, -0.15, -0.8, 0.5, 1.175, 3.1, 4.25, 2.25, 0.25, -1.675)
```

For example we have two columns:

```
V1  V2
M   1.2
A  -0.15
T  -0.8
A   0.5
N   1.175
S   3.1
I   4.25
I   2.25
V   0.25
L  -1.675
```

If there are at least 5 consecutive values above 0 found, print the corresponding letters.

For the example above, the output would be: ANSIIV.

There might be more that one listing above 0 and number of rows can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R` with `ave` and `rle`

```
subset(df, V2 >0 & ave(V2, with(rle(V2 > 0),
       rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = length) >= 5 )
```

-output

```
#   V1    V2
#4  A 0.500
#5  N 1.175
#6  S 3.100
#7  I 4.250
#8  I 2.250
#9  V 0.250
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("M", "A", "T", "A", "N", "S", "I", "I", 
"V", "L"), V2 = c(1.2, -0.15, -0.8, 0.5, 1.175, 3.1, 4.25, 2.25, 
0.25, -1.675)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to group the output this way but it fails: subset(aggregate(df, by = V2) >0 & ave(V2, with(rle(V2 > 0),
       rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = length) >= 5 ).  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @student24 Not clear why you are doing the `aggregate` around the `ave` because `ave` is doing a grouping by

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`'s `rleid` to create a group of consecutive values above 0 and select those groups which have more than 5 rows in them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>% group_by(grp = rleid(V2 > 0)) %>% filter(n() >= 5 & all(V2 > 0))

#   V1     V2   grp
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 A      0.5      3
#2 N      1.18     3
#3 S      3.1      3
#4 I      4.25     3
#5 I      2.25     3
#6 V      0.25     3
```

We can also implement this in `data.table` :

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N >= 5 & all(V2 > 0)], rleid(V2 > 0)]
```

The `grp` column will help to differentiate unique groups if there are multiple in data.

**data**

```
V1 <- c( "M", "A", "T", "A", "N", "S", "I", "I", "V", "L")
V2 <- c( 1.2, -0.15, -0.8, 0.5, 1.175, 3.1, 4.25, 2.25, 0.25, -1.675)
df <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```